# How to xml file by excluding some nodes which follow a certain condition in linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In the following xml data i need to read entire xml data by excluding the last node which contains some child nodes also.

```
<entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="accountnumber" />
    <attribute name="primarycontactid" />
    <attribute name="address1_city" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="or" isquickfindfields="1">
      <condition attribute="name" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="accountnumber" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="emailaddress1" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="telephone1" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="telephone2" operator="like" value="{0}" />
    </filter>
</entity>
```

Now how can get the following data respectively

```
<filter type="or" isquickfindfields="1">
      <condition attribute="name" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="accountnumber" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="emailaddress1" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="telephone1" operator="like" value="{0}" />
      <condition attribute="telephone2" operator="like" value="{0}" />
</filter>
```

and then

```
<filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
</filter>
```

and finally

```
<attribute name="name" />
<attribute name="accountnumber" />
<attribute name="primarycontactid" />
<attribute name="address1_city" />
<attribute name="telephone1" />
<attribute name="emailaddress1" />
<attribute name="accountid" />
<order attribute="name" descending="false" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the xml into an `XElement` using [`XElement.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var root = XElement.Parse("your-xml-string");
```

To get the **or** filter use the following query:

```
var orFilter = root.Descendants("filter")
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("type").Value == "or");
```

The same goes for the **and** filter:

```
var andFilter = root.Descendants("filter")
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("type").Value == "and");
```

And to get the **attribute** elements:

```
var attributeElements = root.Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name != "filter");
```

Be careful not to use `Descendants()` method in the query above because it will return also the descendants of **filter** elements.